# JQuery- Animation Pop Up

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I have a thumbnail images page and want to create animation popup windows.  When I click on a thumbnail, I would like to have a small window show up right on that thumbnail and then get larger while running to the center of the page to show more details about that thumbnail.

I searched and found [one solution here](http://wayfarerweb.com/jquery/plugins/wowwindow/), but when I downloaded the code and tested, popup windows showed, but no animation!  I wonder why?

Do you have any other ways to create animation popup windows?  Please give me a hand.

Thanks!

Comment: Which kind of animation do you want?

Comment: When I click on a thumbnail, I would like to have a small window show up right on that thumbnail and then get larger while running to the center of the page.  Do you have some ways to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library. 
[Click here](https://github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/)

See example - 
[example](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/)

Comment: Thank you very much, Riken!  but somehow it doesn't show the animation.  Do you have any other samples which show animation popup?  Thanks